# Is there a way to set up MongoDB ttl indexes using prisma

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prisma, ttl

I am trying to make a Hotel website backend that allows users to reserve rooms using GraphQL and prisma. I want to make sure that the reservation will be cancelled after the check-in time if no one has checked in. To do this I wanted to set up a ttl index that will delete the reservation.

If there is any alternative way of doing this you can help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

take a look on this : https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/indexes

```
model Post {
  id      Int    @id
  title   String @db.VarChar(255)
  content String @db.Text

  @@fulltext([title, content])
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).